# Microsoft Office SharePoint Virus Scan Engine

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development, anti-virus, sdk

We have a requirement to integrate an antivirus solution with the Sharepoint server programmatically.

Requirement:
When a user adds/updates a document perform a scan using SDK of the antivirus and based on the result allow/block the document. So we are expecting to receive a callback when a user uploads/downloads any documents. This does not apply to the Sharepoint online. We have to achieve this programmatically(C# is the preferred language).

We are struggling to find enough documentation regarding the same.

The documentation we can find so far is mentioned below but it doesn't seem to have enough information to get started and also we are not sure if it is still relevant,
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/aa979485(v=office.14)

We would like to know possible approaches/documentation related to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in SharePoint online,please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/virus-detection-in-spo?view=o365-worldwide (Please note When a file is found to contain a virus, it's flagged so that it can't be downloaded again,however there is no detection during the file upload process)。

If you are in SharePoint On-Premise, please refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-or-2016-configure-antivirus-settings-and-features/

More infromation:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bab1a929-d98e-40a8-9a85-5ccc0177f3cc/onprem-antivirus-solution-for-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-you-use-file-level-antivirus-software-in-sharepoint-01cbc532-a24e-4bba-8d67-0b1ed733a3d9?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have made a mistake in specifying the requirements. I have updated the question. We need to do this programmatically as we will be given SDK of the antivirus and we need to invoke appropriate functions of the SDK on callbacks. Let me know if you need more clarification.